# What do you do if a post is low quality; doesn't really warrant deletion

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing a [post tonight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170112/notification-in-swift-every-day-at-a-set-time/31170280#31170280) that was not a helpful answer at all IMO. What do you guys do if the post doesn't fully answer an OP's question? I don't want to say "Looks Ok" as it really isn't, would you just skip or go ahead and delete it?

Comment: Alright. I don't see a way to comment as to why, or what should be done to improve the post. I suppose I just leave a comment on the post itself explaining why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downvoting is appropriate in this context.  If you think that it *could* be improved, then leave a comment for the OP to come back and explain it.

Comment: When I down vote it and leave a comment, do I just skip it at that point as far as the review options are concerned? Marking it as ok doesn't seem like the right choice

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with any other option, then skipping it is fine.